# App Engine chat application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp

I am writing a chat application on app engine using xmpp. My idea is to allow users to chat to one another. I can get messages to send to a google talk account, by taking the logged in user and removing the @gmail.com part of the address and replacing it with @appid.appspotchat.com )so for example if the logged in user is bob@gmail.com, the jid used to send from will be bob@appid.appspotchat.com). You can then send messages to an google talk account, e.g. jeff@gmail.com.

My problem is in receiving the messages back again. The developer pages show how the app itself can receive messages to the appid@appspot.com jid, but how do you get it to receive messages to the appid.appspot.com jid, and then present these messages tp the logged in user? The overall idea is when a user logs in, I will retrieve thri contact list, get the presence of their contacts (replacing gmail.com with appid.appspotchat.com) then present the available contacts to the user.

If this is not possible, is there a way to let the logged in user chat to other users in a different way? Ive briefly looked at the channel api but i don't think this is suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Channel API to send a message down to a client when your server gets a message intended for that user. There's no facility to direct a XMPP message *directly* to a user on your own page; the XMPP API is used to send messages to users signed in to XMPP clients (such as Gmail, Pidgin, etc).

Comment: Thank you, I am currently going down the route of giving each user a @appid.appspotchat.com jid, based on their gmail address, and then when a message is received by one of these addresses by a handler, it it stored in memcache so the user can retrieve it by checking the memcache every 30 seconds or so. I will look at the channels api however for performing this message passing

Comment: Basically the Channel API takes away the need to poll. Your current plan will work too, as long as you don't mind the possibility of dropped messages if your memcache is flushed.

Comment: I currently have a handler that receives all xmpp messages directed to all users then does the memcache write from there. Do you know if it is possible to use the channels api in this case, so e.g. a user logs in, opens a channel, with say their jid as a token, then the server just sends messages to a new channel with the token that they have recieved a message for?

Comment: When the user logs in, you'd need to create a channel on their client page. You could use their JID as the clientid for that channel. Then, when your app receives a message for that user, just use channel.send_message() to send to the clientid corresponding to the JID that the message is for.

Comment: Do you know of an example where the channel is created on the user side, or provide some code example? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the channel. API similar to UDP, so you have the channel on the server, you set the client id in the channelmessage then just send it on that channel and it will rech the correct client channel?

Comment: Here are the docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview

Comment: You create a channel token, using a clientid of your choice, on the server side and pass it to the client (generally when you're rendering a page). Then you send messages from the server to the client identified by the clientid.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I've found this example application (which is chat in itself) so will look at what they have done 
http://code.google.com/p/partychapp/source/browse/

Comment: Aah this works very well! In fact, I can completely remove the xmpp part and just go via the channels, which will remove the need to process the messages in the middle saving some of the cpu time (and suits the chat part much better than polling as it makes it easier to update the page without having to call a servlet to fetch the messages)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `anything@your_app_id.appspot.com`. Instead you must use `anything@your_app_id.appspotchat.com` as described in [XMPP Addresses](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview#XMPP_Addresses).

Comment: Yeah sorry meant to put that when i typed it (now corrected). Do you know how a user can receive messages destined to a particular anything@appid.appspotchat.com jid, as if it were their own address?

Comment: This should work: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview#Receiving_Chat_Messages

Comment: Thanks ive seen these pages. If the address bob@appid.appspotchat.com is sent to, will all of these requests go to the same handler, and if so how can bob get hold of these messages? To me it seems like the handler is more useful for automatic processing of the messages in the background without concerning users (e.g. for a chatbot).

Comment: I assume this can be done utilising the datastore but I am trying to avoid that as it will not help the quotas if you have to check write every message sent via the app over it

Comment: The requests will definitely be served by multiple frontend instances, so you need a permanent storage, like datastore or ay least memcache.

Comment: Ive tested that and all messages to any @appid.appspotchat.com go to the same handler, so i assume I would have to write the messages to the datastore and then check the datastore regularly to retrieve the messages fore the user. Do you know of a way to do this without the datastore, as it will destroy my quotas having to write every message to the datastore.

Comment: Memcache or possibly a backend instance (although this requires paid account as free quota is only 8h/day)

Comment: Sorry, my 2nd to last comment didnt appear for me so i sent again. Thanks for your help, I will look into using the datastore and other ways to get the data to the user and then delete it as soon as it is received by the user (i am building a chat program with some level of anonymity to observers so all the messages stored in the datastore would be pretty insecure:)  )